# How to route output/input from one terminal to another...?

Tags: c, ubuntu, stream, terminal

I am using Ubuntu. I have written code to open another terminal application using C program. Now I want to route the output " hello world " to new started terminal window...? Can anyone tell me the code or procedure to implement it...?

Comment: Could you post the code you use to start the application?

Comment: what you want ? what you do so far? and why this require?

Comment: #include "stdio.h"

int main(void)
{

    system("gnome-terminal");
 printf("Hello world\n");
 
    return 0;
}

Comment: @Maddy post code to your question window not here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the Terminal using system("gnome-terminal")

Then sleep for 1 seconds, then open /dev/pts and read the file one by one and get the name.

With the help of that name get the status of the file and compare the access time of the file like

```
if(Old_time < Status.st_atime)
 {
   Name=File_Name->d_name;
   Old_time=Status.st_atime;
 }
```

With the help of the final name open the file with open system call.

Then dup2 the older STDOUT to this return descriptor.

Then the output is print to another descriptor.